# Setting Up Nfs Server

Tags: server, nfs, client

I am a new student of Linux. I am having a challenge as ragards setting up an NFS server. I have one Desktop running Ubuntu 13.4 and I need to set up an NFS server and then mount and share files between the server and client. 
Can I use one system for this task that is, set up both client and server on this machine or Do I have to use two systems? One for server and the other for client.
If the NFS server and client can be set on one system please how do I go about it?

I will be grateful for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I undestand your problem. If you only have one computer why do you even want NFS? this should tell you all you need
[https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo‎](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo%E2%80%8E)

Comment: It is best to provide an answer rather than to just send a link. If you could add the relevant information to the answer then link tot he source that would be great.